# Concern regarding piece of code

Tags: java

I was looking at one of the open source project on github and I found following line of code in Java,

```
static byte[] byteArray = new byte[1 << 11];
```

here we know that 1 << 11 is nothing but 2048, so I can directly initialize array by giving its length = 2048 as follow,

`static byte[] byteArray = new byte[2048];`

then why it is written like 1 << 11 instead of 2048 directly.

Comment: Purely a matter of style. They could have writen 2048, or 0x800, or in Java 7 and later 0b100000000000, but apparently they felt that it was useful to emphasize that the only bit set is bit 11 (and perhaps were coding before Java 7 or were unaware of Java 7's binary literals).

Comment: May be they are more intrested in Bit Shifting Magic instead of just putting a number. Although its purely a matter how one codes. :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason to use a bit wise operation is to make it clear this is a power of 2. I have seen people confuse the constant. e.g. 8096 which is a combination of 8192 and 4096.

What I prefer to do is use `<< 10` or `<< 20` for KB and MB. e.g. `2 << 10` for `2 KB`

Comment: @Divers readable is a matter of taste, but `Math.pow` is a `double` so I would say not,

Comment: @Peter it can be downcast into `int`

Comment: @MarkYisri indeed but then you get `(int) Math.pow(2, 11)` or you could have `2 << 10` for `2 KB`

Comment: @PeterLawrey is shift operation (1 << 11) necessary to show a power of 2 value, can't we write 2048 directly and add comment to show power of 2 value or is there any other way around?

Comment: @MJP You could, but this gets harder for bigger numbers e.g. 4 MB (4 << 20) is it 4194304 or 4193404 Would most people recognise 2048. I know people get 4096 and 8192 confused.